# How to scrape a table that is populated by javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am learning scraping. [Scraping site](http://lrc.bih.nic.in/ViewRor.aspx?DistCode=36&SubDivCode=2&CircleCode=9).

I am able to select:

[image: जिला:, अनुमंडल:, अंचल:]

from dropdown using selenium.

I can select from `मौजा का नाम चुने:`.

[image]

Afterwards, I am able to click on the `खाता खोजें` button.

[image]

As a result, a table is populated at the bottom by javascript.

[image]

The button's div code:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$BtnSearch" value="खाता खोजें" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$BtnSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;S&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch" style="width:146px;">
```

Pagination is done by:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1','Page$11')
```

I am not able to scrape this table.

What I have tried:

1. phantomjs isn't supported with selenium
2. Table's id, `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1`, is not in HTML source code. Tried some approaches, no luck so far.

```py
#p_element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1')

p_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]')

print(p_element.text)


path_for_table='//*[@id="aspnetForm"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]'

table_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(path_for_table))

print(table_list)
```

Pages I have looked at:

- [Selenium scraping JS loaded pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456651/selenium-scraping-js-loaded-pages)
- [How to Scrape Data from JavaScript-based Website Using Python, Selenium, and Headless Web Driver](https://medium.com/@mahmudahsan/how-to-scrap-data-from-javascript-based-website-using-python-selenium-and-headless-web-driver-531c7fe0c01f)
- [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping ajax pages using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390257/scraping-ajax-pages-using-python)

Comment: @Harun, i could not find it useful. probably bad on my part

Comment: @aLearner what to do in the case of "मौजा का नाम चुनें / Please Select the Name of Mauza"?

Comment: @Yatin, this means, select a village name. So somebody needs to click on this (in this case selenium). [Once you select this "MAUJA" and click on "खाता खोजें" button, you will have a table in the bottom part of the page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's get the site. I am using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape along with Selenium.

```py
import bs4 as Bs
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = 'D:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get('http://lrc.bih.nic.in/ViewRor.aspx?DistCode=36&SubDivCode=2&CircleCode=9')
```

Then click on a village name (change according to your need)

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]').click()
```

click on "खाता खोजें" button:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch"]').click()
```

Get the page's source using BeautifulSoup

```py
page_src = Bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

find the id: `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel2` and find all `td`s in it:

```py
table_elements = page_src.find("div",{"id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel2"}).find_all("td")
```

Get columns and get the text out of them

```py
columns = table_elements[:6]
column_names = [e.text for e in header]
```

`columns`:

```py
[<td>क्रम</td>,
 <td>रैयतधारी का नाम</td>,
 <td style="white-space:nowrap;">पिता/पति का नाम</td>,
 <td>खाता संख्या</td>,
 <td>खेसरा संख्या</td>,
 <td>अधिकार<br/>अभिलेख</td>]
```

`column_names`:

```py
['क्रम',
 'रैयतधारी का नाम',
 'पिता/पति का नाम',
 'खाता संख्या',
 'खेसरा संख्या',
 'अधिकारअभिलेख']
```

Next get the body of the table

```py
body_of_table = table_elements[6:-4]
```

Then create chunks of 6 columns for each entry and get the text out

```py
chunks = [body_of_table[x:x+6] for x in range(0, len(body_of_table), 6)]
data = [[e.text.strip('\n') for e in chunk] for chunk in chunks]
```

`data:`

```py
[['1', 'अरूण कुमार', 'शिवलाल पासवान', '55', '406', 'देखें'],
 ['2', 'इन्द्रदेव प्रसाद', '\xa0', '98', '789', 'देखें'],
 ['3', 'ईश्वर मांझी', 'चमारी मांझी', '78', '42', 'देखें'],
 ['4', 'कवलसिया देवी', 'तुलसी मांझी', '120', '41', 'देखें'],
 ['5', 'कामदेव पांडे', 'शिवदानी पांडे', '210', '457, 459, 461, 474', 'देखें'],
 ['6', 'कामेश्वर मांझी', 'उत्ती मांझी', '78', '43', 'देखें'],
 ['7', 'कारू मांझी', 'राधे मांझी', '78', '42', 'देखें'],
 ['8', 'कारू मांझी', 'मेघन मांझी', '78', '42', 'देखें'],
 ['9', 'कौशल्या देवी', 'केदार महतो', '253', '757', 'देखें'],
 ['10', 'गणेश साव', 'छेदी साव', '156', '236', 'देखें'],

....
```

Now `import Pandas` and use it to create a dataframe out of this list of lists:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = column_names)

# set क्रम as index
df.set_index(df.columns[0])
```

Final result:

```py
import time # using time.sleep for illustration only. You should use explicit wait
import bs4 as Bs
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = 'D:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get('http://lrc.bih.nic.in/ViewRor.aspx?DistCode=36&SubDivCode=2&CircleCode=9')

time.sleep(4)

#click on a village name
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)

# click on खाता खोजें
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch"]').click()

time.sleep(2)


# ----------- table extracting part ------------------


# get page source
page_src = Bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

# find the id: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel2 and find all tds in it
table_elements = page_src.find("div",{"id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel2"}).find_all("td")

# get columns and get the text out of them
columns = table_elements[:6]
column_names = [e.text for e in header]

# get the body of the table
body_of_table = table_elements[6:-4]

# create chunks of 6 columns for each entry
chunks = [body_of_table[x:x+6] for x in range(0, len(body_of_table), 6)]

# get the text out
data = [[e.text.strip('\n') for e in chunk] for chunk in chunks]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = column_names)

# set क्रम as index
df.set_index(df.columns[0])

print(df)
```

[image]

...

---

To scape the next pages:

- Click on the next button using Selenium.
- Wait for the page to load
- Rerun the table extracting part (by putting it into a function)
- discard the column names (we already have them)
- append data into the already created data frame
- repeat the above steps of all pages (you can add a while loop and try clicking on a page till an exception occurs, [see try and except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp))