# How to switch from IE to XMLHTTP60

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I need to switch from ie to xmhttp60, and get the result of the execScript. Is there any way to do it? Below the code
I'm using.

```
Sub MostrarMasButton()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy

    url = "https://es.investing.com/equities/amazon-com-inc-earnings"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url
    
    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    ie.document.parentWindow.execScript ("showMoreEarningsHistory(6435, this)")
             
End Sub
```

Comment: XmlHttpRequest objects cannot execute JavaScript, only browsers do that.  (If `showMoreEarningsHistory()` issues an Ajax request then that's what you would need to invoke with an XmlHttpRequest)

Comment: @Alex K, I've seen in the dev tools->Network tab there is actually an XHR with an Ajax issued. but honestly I don't know how to use it. The URL it shows seems to be dynamic and I need to run this same sequence for all the stocks not just for amazon. I'm really stuck at this point. I've opened a question  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64288496/vba-scraping-with-javascript-troubles-to-use-execscript) which show what I need, but I haven't received any positive answer. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: From the description of this thread and from the description of the referenced thread, I understand that you want to click the click the **Mostrar más** button until it displays all the table data. I suggest you refer to this [example](https://freetexthost.net/pNqKoWKz). Try to run it on your side and let us know whether it is working or not.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I'm not using iE but XMLHTTP. Please refer to this [link] (https://freetexthost.net/OyWkqrGY) to see exactly what Im looking for.